# Java script in the wordpress subfolder not running due to .htaccess file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have wordpress installation on root folder. and i have tool with java script on a subfolder called smart inside the root folder.

in my site http://www.jump2health.com/smart, the page doesn’t show up all the java script it is supposed to. where as i have uploaded it in a different place (http://billmath.com/smart/) and it works as expected. when i rename (remove) the .htaccess file which is in root the java script works as expected, however this stops my word press site from working normally.

My htaccess file in wordpress installation is as follows:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I dont have any .htaccess file inside my subfolder.

after extensive search tried every thing that I found on google search results with no success
I tried adding a .htaccess file inside subfolder with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine off
</IfModule>
```

That didn't help either

I tried ignoring the folder from main htccess file in root which didn't work.

I tried many more please help me where is the catch

I am new to wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `.htaccess` file of your Wordpress like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(smart|smart/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Basically if user is trying to access `/smart/` directory, the program flow will be not executed by front controller of Wordpress, so the rewrite rule will not match.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(smart|smart/.*)$
```

Comment: That Didn't help.. am i missing any thing here.